# passing href attributes to another php page

Tags: php, anchor

.a little help guys..

I have an index.php page which contains  tags which when clicked opens up picture.php.
.my picture.php is a page that retrieves images from a certain database depending on what is the idno.

.what i want to do is to add an "idno" attribute on my anchor tag that when the user clicks a certain  tag the index.php sends the idno to my picture.php so that the picture.php knows what image to fetch from the database. help pls!

Answer (score 3):

So for your anchor tag, could you do something like this?

```
<?php
    $url = "pictures.php?idno=" . idno;
    echo "<a href=\"" . $url . "\">Click Me</a>";
?>
```

Now in your `pictures.php` file, you can read the ID like this:

```
$idno = $_GET['idno'];
```

The only thing to watch out for is to make sure you sanitize that input, before you pass it off to a database query so you aren't vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the parameter to `picture.php` via GET

```
<a href="picture.php?id=894754093857">Blah!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use GET to pass idno to pictures.php

so your link would look like this:

```
<a href='/picture.php?idno=12345678'>My Picture Tag</a>
```

In your picture.php:

```
$idno = $_GET['idno'];
```

Make sure you sterilize $idno before using it in a MySQL query. If idno is a number, then you can also check if it's an integer:

```
$isInt = is_int($idno);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="picture.php?idno=<?php echo $idno ?>">Picture # <?php echo $idno ?></a>
```

Figuring out how to set $idno is left as an exercise to the OP.