# sending variables from <a> to javascript, from javascript to <form value>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have the following codes:

code1:

```
<div name="content">
    <a id="various3" href="picture.php" title="<?php echo $info; ?> " idno="5" >
        <img class="last" src="./images/page11.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

code2:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var imagelinks = $('div[name=content] a');
        idno = imagelinks.attr('idno');
        document.getElementById("pid").value = idno;
</script>
```

code3:

```
<form id="target" method="get" action="picture.php?=">
    <input id="pid" name="pid" value="" />
```

code4:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pw = '';
$db = 'thepillar';
$phpVar = $_GET["pid"];

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw); 
mysql_select_db($db); 
$sql = "select pics, ext from infopics where id='$phpVar'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Bad query at 12!'.mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $db_img = $row['pics'];
    $type = $row['ext'];
} 
$img = base64_decode($db_img); //print_r($db_img );
$img = imagecreatefromstring($img);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);

?>
```

.code1, code2, and code3 are on the same page index.php, while code4 is on another page picture.php.

the flow that i want to have is that when index.php loads code2 assigns every  tag inside  as imagelinks, and then declare a javascript variable idno and then sets the idno attribute in my  tag in code1 as its value.

```
idno = imagelinks.attr('idno');
```

next up

```
document.getElementById("pid").value = idno;
```

this code sets the javascript variable idno as the value for the input id="pid" in my code3. as a result a textbox appears on my index.php containing the value from my code3.

.what i want to do is to pass the pid value to code4 in my picture.php and store it as the value of $phpVar

```
$phpVar = $_GET["pid"];
```

and it is performed when i click the  tag inside code1 instead of using a .

Comment: Is this post a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160247/passing-href-attributes-to-another-php-page ? Why not edit the first one as it is unsolved ?

Comment: Also, adding a non-existing attribute (idno) to an html element won't be working in a lot of browsers, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability. Never use variables that the user can change ($_GET for example) in SQL queries. Use PDO instead, or if you can't use that, at least use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your `$sql` before you do `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox - yes it is. i'm so sorry for that. i'm just all confused right now for this project is for my thesis. T_T

Comment: .@itchy - i used mysql_real_escape_string() but still nothing changes.

Comment: @Menahem: It returns a jQuery wrapper, that's the basic principle of jQuery. In the get attribute case it return either the value of the first element or undefined, see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L788

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: What are you talking about? Non-standard attributes have been part of the HTML standard forever. You have to be careful when accessing them from JavaScript, though, but it works in all browsers.

Comment: @erikkallen : Exact the fact that i switch to xhtml, where it don't even pass validation, most of the time made me believe this. It's totally non standard before html5 and even there only data-* attribute are specified but it works in real life. It's one of the quirks that some relies on that make browsers so unstable and hard to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the jQuery inside `$(document).ready` could be written more simply like so:

```
$('#pid').val($('div[name=content] a').attr('idno'));
```

If you then want to send that to the php, you could add something like:

```
$('#various3 img').click(function(){
    $('#target').submit();
});
```

Which will submit the form when the image is clicked.

I would also second the commenter's advice regarding SQL sanitizing and not using arbitrary HTML attributes.